# How to read space separated integers in racket

Tags: racket

I looked at the documentation https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/input-and-output.html but I find it to be very confusing and I feel like it contains a lot of extra information I don't need for such a simple task.

I would like to read two space separated integers and store them in variables.

example input:

1 2

I would like to define and x and y whose values are 1 and 2 respectively.

Comment: It would help to know where you are getting these from. A file? User interaction in DrRacket? Etc.

Comment: Is it part of the source code or something that is passed in by the user when the program runs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a *lot* of ways to do this. I’ll give you three.

### Option 1: Use the built-in `read`

The `read` function reads s-expressions. Conveniently, integers are valid s-expressions, and it skips whitespace, too. This means you can just call `read` twice on an input port to produce two datums:

```
> (let ([in (open-input-string "1 2")])
    (values (read in) (read in)))
1
2
```

This has a drawback, though: there are a lot of things that are valid s-expressions that *aren’t* numbers, so you might get a lot of garbage back if you’re not careful. For example:

```
> (let ([in (open-input-string "#f (hello world)")])
    (values (read in) (read in)))
#f
'(hello world)
```

You’d probably need to do some post-processing to ensure what you get back is what you expect. This also won’t necessarily consume all the input, so if it’s important there’s nothing else after the numbers, you’d need to check that separately, too.

### Option 2: Use a regular expression

Regular expressions are a pretty easy way to handle simple cases like this. In this example, the regexp literal `#px"^(\\d+) (\\d+)$"` is a simple way to express the pattern you mention in your question. You can use this to extract the numeric parts of the string:

```
> (regexp-match #px"^(\\d+) (\\d+)$" "1 2")
'("1 2" "1" "2")
```

You can combine this with `string->number` to get numbers out:

```
> (let ([matches (regexp-match #px"^(\\d+) (\\d+)$" "1 2")])
    (values (string->number (second matches))
            (string->number (third matches))))
1
2
```

This has the advantage of ensuring the input matches precisely, and it’s safe, fast, and simple. However, one downside is that it will not provide good error messages if the parsing fails, `regexp-match` will simply produce `#f`.

### Option 3: Use a parser combinator library

Racket has a number of libraries designed for parsing. These can scale to parsing far more complicated things that two numbers, but they also work fine for simple situations. I will show an example using [`megaparsack`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/megaparsack/index.html), since it’s my library, and I like it.

You can use `megaparsack` to write a parser that parses two integers separated by a space:

```
(require data/applicative
         data/monad
         megaparsack
         megaparsack/text)

(define 2-integers/p
  (do [x <- integer/p]
      (char/p #\space)
      [y <- integer/p]
      (pure (cons x y))))
```

This parser is obviously more complicated than the regexp, but it also does more, and it’s much more extensible and composable. You can use this parser to get the numbers you want:

```
> (parse-result! (parse-string 2-integers/p "1 2"))
'(1 . 2)
```

However, unlike the regular expression, it will automatically provide good error messages when a parse fails:

```
> (parse-result! (parse-string 2-integers/p "1 "))
string:1:1: parse error
  unexpected: end of input
  expected: integer
```